# Is there any special meaning for numbers in braces like {0} or {1} in LDIF files of OpenLDAP?

Tags: openldap

I'm playing a bit with OpenLDAP.

In the configuration LDIF files there are often numbers in braces like {0} or {1}, e.g:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
```

or

```
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.2 NAME 'gecos' DESC 'The GECOS field;
 the common name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
 SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.3 NAME 'homeDirectory' DESC 'The absol
 ute path to the home directory' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4
 .1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.4 NAME 'loginShell' DESC 'The path to
 the login shell' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121
 .1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

Do the {0}, {1} and so on have any special meaning (like parameters) or are they just strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for list ordering: Attributes or entities with the same key are sorted using the number in the braces. Especial need for access control lists, as the ordering of the rules matters, e.g.

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange 
    by self write 
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=mobikat,dc=net" write 
    by anonymous auth 
    by * none
olcAccess: {1}to * 
    by self read 
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=net" write 
    by dn="cn=readonly,dc=mydomain,dc=net" read 
    by * none
```